# How do I get tag text at remove event in tokenize2

Tags: jquery, tokenize2

How to know which text is removed from tokenize2 control tags

**Plugin Link:** https://zellerda.github.io/Tokenize2/events.html

```
$('.tokenize-override-demo1').tokenize2();
$('.tokenize-sample-demo1').on("tokenize:tokens:remove", function (event, value, text){
   console.log("value : "+value); // value is printed
   console.log(text + "option removed"); //text is not printed,Need Text which is removed 
});
```

[image]

Comment: There is no 3rd argument passed to the remove event handler. https://zellerda.github.io/Tokenize2/events.html `text` will always be null

Comment: so how do i get text?

Comment: A lot of these "tag input" widget libraries only give you access to the value because that's what is going to be submitted by the form and ultimately all you care about. The text is only for the end user. I'm assuming your value is an int (primary key). You will probably have to store a map of (id's => friendly text) to use in your JS.

Comment: If your HTML markup for the tag input is a `<select>` then you can query the DOM for the text. something like `$('select').find('option[value="%YOUR_VALUE%"]').text();`

Comment: thanks brother good idea